# Laravel Excel doesnt ignore empty rows with Google Docs

Tags: php, phpexcel, laravel-excel

I'm using this package for Laravel 5 [Laravel Excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs) and works great with Calc. But when I create the same Excel file with the same data in Google Docs, for some reason empty rows are not ignored (Docs adds 1000 rows).

I'm using this code to remove empty cells:

```
    return Excel::load($file, function ($reader) {
        $reader->formatDates(false)->ignoreEmpty();
    });
```

When I create the spreadsheet in Calc works great! It ignores all empty cells and empty rows, someone have faced the same issue here? Im wondering what Google Docs adds to the rows to cause this behavior in the package.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? i'm having the same issue

Comment: @B.J.A.A. After some research I remember that I found somewhere that google docs create this 1000 rows with a empty string. Since Laravel Excel considers rows with empty strings, my solution was to remove all rows with empty strings after reading the entire excel. However that's not the best way :/